# Scoping problem with Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, evaluation, scoping

Consider the following simple code:

```
f = Sin[a x];
Manipulate[
  Plot[f, {x, 0, 10}], 
  {a, 0, 10}]
```

Manipulate takes `f` to be a variable which has no value.

I tried to evaluate `f` as follows:

```
 Manipulate[
   Plot[Evaluate @ f, {x, 0, 10}], 
   {a, 0, 10}]
```

but now I still have a problem with the scope of `a`.

I know one way to do what I want, which is to define `f` as a function of `a` as follows:

```
f[a_] := Sin[a x];
Manipulate[
  Plot[f[a], {x, 0, 10}], 
  {a, 0, 10}]
```

But what if I have many variables and I want to manipulate over all of them?
Is there any way to make `Manipulate` substitute `f` by its value and take all of its symbols as a variables to be manipulated?

Comment: Your last example is the standard way to do what you want. Why do you object to it?

Comment: `Manipulate[Plot[f /. a -> a1, {x, 0, 10}], {a1, 0, 10}]`

Comment: `With[{f=f},Manipulate[...]]`. But why bother? Just do it with a proper function as *m_goldberg* notes. This (and other scoping tricks) are either not needed, bad form, or asking for trouble in most cases. In any case, *read the documentation* - `Manupulate` has "special" behavior...

Comment: @kuba I know this trick but again I will need to replace all manipulating variables.

Comment: @rasher Thanks. With does the trick. I need this because I have a function in which it will take to much time to be evaluated each time I change the manipulating variables.